# Using GDB in timer functions

Tags: c, linux, timer, gdb

I have a C program which uses a timer, when the timer expires the program does something (sets a flag).

My question is: When i set the breakpoints and run the program using GDB, and use "step" to check line by line, does the timer keeps on ticking in the background? or does it halt till i press "s" again (the next step)?

Comment: How is your timer implemented?

Comment: [timer_create](http://linux.die.net/man/3/timer_create)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you used `CLOCK_REALTIME`, yes. The timer will keep ticking along and if you spend a bunch of time looking at a single instruction it will send its signal the next time something in your program is executed. You can use `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` or `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` in Linux after 2.6.12, but those will probably not get you what you want, since they don't measure wall clock time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was very useful info. Adding a question :) I see if i do that (spend a bunch of time :) ) after sometime the timer_delete failed, saying invalid input (that is timer_id) is no longer valid. Why is it so? I used SIGEV_THRAED in timer_setttime and CLOCK_REALTIME in timer_create.